# Learning MVC 3, Seems better to create custom app and integrate with Orchard rather than build module?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I have been deliberating and deliberating. Orchard is clearly powerful and flexible, contains some very sophisticated code. I need to create some specific Wizard/Workflow functionality. I am also using Entity framework instead of NHibernate. It seems to me that it will be better to write this application seperately using simpler code, which I can refactor, and integrate into Orchard via a Wrapper Module, rather than getting caught up in writing a module afresh for the complete Wizard/Workflow. As I say I am learning MVC3 and do not want to overcomplicate my life, just deliver a solution. I will certainly use Orchard for typical CMS website features.

I also still have an unresolved issue of representing Organisations above users, which I have already resolved outside Orchard. This is only needed for the application rather than content management. So in the short term it may be that I keep the authentication seperate.

Does this sound the most pragmatic approach. If there was a good existing module then the decision would be easier. I think they are considering workflow for 1.7, but we are not there yet.

Many thanks,

Ed

Comment: Bertrand, if you can put comment in answer then I can award mark. I still have a feeling about the use of the rules module, but I think it is too early. I am now looking into ViewModels and WF4.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like a safe path, yes.